# assign date value into native base datepicker

Tags: react-native, native-base

Using nativebase datepick:

this.state.date value is `2019-11-15T00:00:00+00:00`

```
             <DatePicker
                defaultDate={
                  this.state.date
                    ? new Date(this.state.date) : null
```

problem is the datepicker show `14 November 2019`, because of converting to phone timezone.

I can also use momentjs library.

Comment: You can use moment library to format date before setting default state value

Answer (score 0):

I think `moment.utc(yourDateHere)`could help you :)

Here is an example of how it works:

[Moment dates example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGRpe.png)